# Share SSL lets-encrypt on 2 debian web server for same websites

Tags: apache, ssl, debian, lets-encrypt

I need community help to share a ssl https certificate generate with let's encrypt on server to another:

I have 2 web servers on Debian Apache 2.4 (debian jessie) that are accessible behind one ip public address via load balancer (host in a private cloud). 
Both sharing the two same web sites (sighno.fr and plateforme.sighno.fr) 
Why this ? cause we need HA on this websites, if one server goes down the other is still up to ensure service and connexion.

I have generate auto certificate on the server 1 but i launch the procedure on server 2 let's encrypt tells me that the certificate is already generate (logical!)

How can i make it work on server knowing this certificate is hosted on server1.

Share certificate folder from server 1 to server 2 ? 
Where should i change the configuration of let's encrypt on server 2 to make it understand ?

I want to say before someone proposing me this solution that my hoster doesn't want to host the certificate on his load balancer..

Thank you by advance for your help.

Comment: There are many ways to sync files between servers. The easiest way is SSH, using `scp` command + `crontab`. Another way is `rsync`. Network share may not be very reliable.

Comment: OK problem solved. you need to copy or rsync or scp /etc/letsencrypt/live/* and copy vhost apache2 configuration.